# Predicting the class label using logistic regression/decision tree in Orange

Tags: machine-learning, classification, orange

I have data with 12 attributes and a class label no/yes. I have created a model with the train data. I tried to test the model with test data by removing the class label. Got "ValueError("Test data set without class attributes")"
How to actually predict the class label in decision tree/Logistic regression?

I have made the following connections in Orange.

file->  Data sampler ->

```
               -> logistic regression -> test learners -> Confusion Matrix
               -> logistic regression -> Predictions
               -> Remaining data -> test learners   
               -> Remaining data -> Predictions
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the class. Orange does it internally.

If you use Test learners, don't use Data sampler. Test learners samples the data.

You first line will run cross validation (or whatever you set up in Test Learners). Just remove Data sampler from this pipeline in you're OK.

The second line needs to go like this: from data sample, give the Data Sample to Logistic regression and Remaining data to Predictions. Also connect Logistic regression to Predictions. Predictions will show you the predictions for the remaining data, using a model constructed from the data sample. Don't remove classes from Remaining data. Don't worry, Logistic regression won't use it to make predictions. And, besides, you'll be able to compare the actual and the predicted class in Predictions.

I don't understand the third and the fourth line. Anyway, the first two represent the two common scenarios.